# SketchFlow / SketchStyles is empty. ((Assets) Styles > SketchStyles)

Tags: sketchflow, expression-sketchflow

I just installed the Expression Blend Studio 4 (Trial) from Microsoft.

I have several tutorials telling me to change the style, that I should go to
(Assets) Styles  > SketchStyles

There is nothing under that area except a warning(and link)

***This category shows all the styles you have created for the current document or application.  Additional styles can be found in the online Expression Gallery.***

That link gets me no where fast.  It basically goes to the home page of Expression Blend.

If you look at this 90 second video.

http://electricbeach.org/files/sketchflow_overview.wmv

At the 30-36 second mark, he is switching the style from squiggly to something more professional.

I'm trying to demo that same thing, which I believe (keep in mind I'm new to this) I am changing FROM the WigglyStyles style to something else.

With 
(Assets) Styles  > SketchStyles
being empty, I don't know what I'm missing.

...........

So a 2 part question:

1. How do I get entries to show up under (Assets) Styles  > SketchStyles?
2. (If different from #1), how do I change the overall style from WigglyStyles to something else (and back to WigglyStyles)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is misssing the SketchStyles.xaml.

SketchStyles.xaml – this file contain the resource dictionary with number of styles which SketchFlow project makes use of them internally.

Solution:
Create a new solution, a (sketchflow silverlight solution), copy the SketchStyles.xaml from your created solution drag and drop the to the project that doesn't have this file, and press ctrl+shift+B to build it.

hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The ***message*** was throwing me off.

The little triangle, pointed "to the right" initially, has to be clicked (and then points down) exposing the sub items.

The message:

***This category shows all the styles you have created for the current document or application. Additional styles can be found in the online Expression Gallery.***

is what was throwing me off.  (And I was thinking the same thing as alimbada, that my install went awry).

Once I expand "Styles" (via the small triangle), everything is there.

Ok!! Did I mention I'm a developer, not a designer?? (haha).
Aka, this was just a big "duh" moment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick play with Sketchflow since I have Blend installed and those styles show up fine. Maybe your install went awry?